# Multivariate Analysis and AOR

Tags: multivariate-analysis, odds-ratio, bivariate

[image]

[image]

Hello All, I understand how we can calculate the Bivariate analyses using the table 3 in table 4. But can anyone please help me understand how to calculate Multivariate analyses using AOR. Are there any formulas or anything to calculate these?

Comment: You would need the original data to do a multivariable regression you cannot back-calclate it from the adjusted odds ratios if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The adjusted odds ratio is the result of a logistic regression analysis. Very little short of having the entire dataset would enable you to calculate these values.